# Conversion from Azimuth to counterclockwise angle

Tags: geometry

How can I convert azimuth angles to the usual 0-360 counterclockwise angle in degrees where

> East = 0, North = 90, West = 180, South = 270

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For matlab's notion of azimuth (i.e. N=0, W=270, S=180, E=90 that runs clockwise) the answer's simple. For azimuth $a$, compute $h = 450 - a$; if $h > 360$, return $h - 360$; otherwise return $h$.

For the remainder of this answer, I'm going to assume that by "Azimuth angles" you mean something like 135E or 37W, which mean (respectively), "135 degrees east of north" (or "clockwise from north") and "37 degrees west of north (or "counterclockwise from north").

Here's a general rule, assuming that for an azimuth like 47E, we say that the number, $n$, is $47$, and the "name" is "E".

1. If the name on the azimuth angle is "W", simply return $n + 90$
2. If the name is "E" ...

   a. If $n \le 90$, return $90 - n$.

   b. Otherwise, return $450- n$

As examples:

40W ---> 40+90 = 130 degrees [Rule 1]

150W ---> 150 + 90 = 240 degrees  [Rule 1]

40E ---> 90 - 40 = 50 degrees [Rule 2a]

120E ---> 450-120 = 330 degrees [Rule 2b]

It's worth checking the cardinal points, too:

90E ---> (90-90) = 0 [Rule 2a]

0E ---> 90-0 = 90 [Rule 2a]

90W ---> 90+90 = 180 [Rule 1]

The only remaining question is what to do with 180E or 180W. You'll discover that both paths (Rule 1, or rule 2b) in my formula lead to the answer "270", which is what you want.

Comment: Hi John, thanks! By azimuth I mean the Matlab azimuth, i.e. N=0, W=270, S=180, E=90 that runs clockwise

Comment: In that case, the rule is simpler: given azimuth $a$, compute $h = 450 - a$. If $h > 360$, return $h - 360$; otherwise return $h$.

Comment: Fantastic! that did the trick! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, its just a binary tree. You pick ENWS, and then maybe another one (Like Northwest) and move 45 degrees in that direction. If one primary and one secondary appear (North-Northwest), then it is 22.5 degrees away from each. If it is North by Northwest, or any other "by" direction then you move 11.25 degrees west of North, or from the first thing to the "by" thing. I dont think the system gets any more exact than that.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit please?

Comment: So, in azimuth, there is either a primary direction or a secondary direction at the base of the direction (North, Northwest, West, Southwest, etc) There are 8 of these, and each is 45 degrees away from each other. You could also find the position of one by averaging the values of the two orginal direction. If two directions are combined (e.g. NorthNorthwest), then you find the one equally between them (22.5 degrees off) If they use the word "by" then it is 11.25 degrees off.

Comment: Its hard to turn words into numbers